# Make phone field required if certain shipping method is selected

Tags: 6, ubercart

I use drupal 6 and ubercart 2. My aim is to make phone field in delivery address required if certain shipping method is selected. I have set up a jquery script that shows a message to the user saying that phone is needed after customer selects the shipping method. Despite of this, some customers don't fill out the phone field. 
I would like to add a non js check after submission of checkout page. 
I suppose I would need to write a small module. A need help with the start of the code

```
<?php
IF 
{[mymethod] = true}
then {
  $form['panes']['delivery']['delivery_phone']['#required'] = true;
}
?>
```

Thank you very much.

EDIT: according to @Adam Balsam answer I tried to make custom module
This is uc_checkout_phone.module

```
<?php
function uc_checkout_phone_uc_cart_checkout_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['panes']['delivery']['delivery_phone']['#element_validate'] = array('uc_checkout_phone_phone_validate');
}
function uc_checkout_phone_phone_validate($element, &$form_state) {
  if (($form_state['panes']['shipping']['shipping_method']['#value'] == 'Doprava - kurier DPD') && ($element['#value'] == '')) {
   form_error($element, t('You must enter a phone number if you select XXX as a shipping method.'));
 dpm($form_state); }
}
?>
```

This is uc_checkout_phone.info

```
name = uc_checkout_phone
description = phone required
core = 6.x
```

The form id should be uc-cart-checkout-form. I had to write it using underscores. The shipping method is Doprava - kuriér DPD, I tried also the value which is flatrate_3---0 but I get no warning message if I let the phone number empty. Where can be the problem?
I named themodule: uc_checkout_phone

Comment: Try [`dpm`ing](http://drupal.org/project/devel) `$form_state` in `uc_checkout_phone_phone_validate()` to ensure your checking the right variable against the right value.

Comment: @Andy I put dpm($form_state); inside the second function (as updated in question) but I can not see any messages from devel. I view checkout page as admin.

Comment: The `dpm()` should be outside the conditional.

Comment: @Andy I put it outside conditional but no messages again. I tried to put dpm() in the first function as well and I got displayed only an empty wrapper for message with no message inside.

Comment: The dpm() should only fire on submission; are you submitting the form? You can use a die() in the validator to ensure that it's being called. If it is being called, and you still have problems seeing the dpm(), you can try using a dd() instead.

Comment: @Andy If in my case submitting the form means to go from checkout page to checkout review page, then yes I am submitting the form. But I can still not see any devel info after inserting die() iside second function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have two functions in your custom module. The first one is [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6):

```
/**
 * This function adds an additional custom validation function to the delivery phone field
 *
 * Make sure you update MYMODULE and YOURFORMID to match your circumstances.
 */
function MYMODULE_form_YOURFORMID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['panes']['delivery']['delivery_phone']['#element_validate'] = array('MYMODULE_phone_validate');
}
```

The second function is the custom validation function that we added using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter above:

```
/**
 * Make sure you update MYMODULE again and update the array to match your shipping method
 */
function MYMODULE_phone_validate($element, &$form_state) {
  if (($form_state['panes']['shipping']['shipping_method']['#value'] == 'THE SHIPPING METHOD') && ($element['#value'] == '')) {
    form_error($element, t('You must enter a phone number if you select XXX as a shipping method.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I could not make it work. Please see the updated question.

Comment: I can't provide any more help than what Andy has provided above. You might want to look into creating a simple module using the example module (http://drupal.org/project/examples) to help you understand some of the basic concepts first.

Comment: I updated my question and added code for the custom module. Please review it if there are any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module is the easiest answer:

> The rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module in core.

Comment: In drupal 6 I can only use conditional actions where there is no check if phone number is empty or not. Or did you mean to write custom php inside CA? Can you elaborate a little bit please?

Comment: well in D6 I guess you cant have entities too, probably  wont work for you, but give it a try, with some custom php you may get what you want. with rules you can state a trigger if Y (a condition custom php to see if your field has value or not) is valid DO x.